# How to always show submenu in vertical menu with this js file?

Tags: javascript, menu, hover, show

My question is if anybody knows what to change in the following js file to always show submenu on the vertical menu , meaning to show the submenu on page load and stay shown whether i hover on it or not, in clear make it part of the vertical menu and not an hidden sub menu that you have to hover on the parent category to access.
What do i need to change in the following code to acomplish that, :
Thanks in advance guys !

```
     * DC Vertical Mega Menu - jQuery vertical mega menu
     * Copyright (c) 2011 Design Chemical

 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 */
(function($){


    //define the new for the plugin ans how to call it  
    $.fn.dcVerticalMegaMenu = function(options){
        //set default options  
        var defaults = {
            classParent: 'dc-mega',
            arrow: true,
            classArrow: 'dc-mega-icon',
            classContainer: 'sub-container',
            classSubMenu: 'sub',
            classMega: 'mega',
            classSubParent: 'mega-hdr',
            classSubLink: 'mega-hdr',
            classRow: 'row',
            rowItems: 3,
            speed: 'fast',
            effect: 'show',
            direction: 'right',
            menubg: '0',
            menufixwidth: '0',
            menufixheight: '0'
        };


        //call in the default otions
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var $dcVerticalMegaMenuObj = this;

        //act upon the element that is passed into the design    
        return $dcVerticalMegaMenuObj.each(function(options){

            $mega = $(this);
            if(defaults.direction == 'left'){
                $mega.addClass('left');
            } else {
                $mega.addClass('right');
            }
            // Get Menu Width
            var megaWidth = $mega.width();


            // Set up menu
            $('> li',$mega).each(function(){

                var $parent = $(this);
                var $megaSub = $('> ul',$parent);



                if($megaSub.length > 0){

                $('> a',$parent).addClass(defaults.classParent).append('<span class="'+defaults.classArrow+'"></span>');
                    $megaSub.addClass(defaults.classSubMenu).wrap('<div class="'+defaults.classContainer+'" />');
                    var $container = $('.'+defaults.classContainer,$parent);
                    if($('ul',$megaSub).length > 0){

                        $parent.addClass(defaults.classParent+'-li');
                        $container.addClass(defaults.classMega);

                        // Set sub headers
                        $('> li',$megaSub).each(function(){
                            $(this).addClass('mega-unit');
                            if($('> ul',this).length){
                                $(this).addClass(defaults.classSubParent);                              
                                $('> a',this).addClass(defaults.classSubParent+'-a');
                            } else {
                                $(this).addClass(defaults.classSubLink);
                                $('> a',this).addClass(defaults.classSubLink+'-a');
                            }
                        });

                            $('> li li',$megaSub).each(function(){
                            if($('> ul',this).length){
                              $(this).addClass('mega-sub3'); //rajib
                               $('.mega-sub3 ul').addClass("show3div");
                            } 
                        });                             

                    } else {
                        $container.addClass('non-'+defaults.classMega);
                        if(defaults.menubg==1){                         
                            var catimages =$('.non-'+defaults.classMega).closest("li").attr('id'); 
                            catimages = catimages.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
                            $('.non-'+defaults.classMega).css('background','#333 url(modules/leftmegamenu/bgimages/'+catimages+'.gif) no-repeat right bottom');
                        }
                    }
                } 

                var $container = $('.'+defaults.classContainer,$parent);
                var subWidth = $megaSub.outerWidth(true);
                var subHeight = $container.height();

                    if(defaults.menufixwidth>0){
                            var subWidth = defaults.menufixwidth;
                            }                           
                    if(defaults.menufixheight>0){
                            var subHeight = defaults.menufixheight; 
                        }

                var itemHeight = $parent.outerHeight(true);
                // Set position to top of parent
                $container.css({                    
                    height: subHeight+'px',
                    width: subWidth+'px',                               
                    zIndex: '1000'
                }).hide();
            });





            // HoverIntent Configuration
            var config = {
                sensitivity: 2, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
                interval: 10, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval
                over: megaOver, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)
                timeout: 0, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
                out: megaOut // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
            };





            $('li',$dcVerticalMegaMenuObj).hoverIntent(config);

            function megaOver(){
                $(this).addClass('mega-hover');
                var $link = $('> a',this);
                var $subNav = $('.sub',this);
                var $container = $('.sub-container',this);
                var width = defaults.menufixwidth;
                var outerHeight = $container.outerHeight();
                var height = defaults.menufixheight;                
                var itemHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
                var offset = $link.offset();
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var offset = offset.top - scrollTop
                var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
                var maxHeight = bodyHeight - offset;
                var xsHeight = maxHeight - outerHeight;

                if(defaults.menubg==1){                         
                            var catimages =$(this).closest("li").attr('id'); 
                            catimages = catimages.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();                                               

                $container.css({
                            background: '#333 url(modules/leftmegamenu/bgimages/'+catimages+'.gif) no-repeat right bottom'
                        });
                }

            if(xsHeight < 0){
                    var containerMargin = xsHeight - itemHeight;
                    $container.css({marginTop: containerMargin+'px'});
                }

                var containerPosition = {right: megaWidth};
                if(defaults.direction == 'right'){
                    containerPosition = {left: megaWidth};
                }

                if(defaults.effect == 'fade'){
                    $container.css(containerPosition).fadeIn(defaults.speed);
                }
                if(defaults.effect == 'show'){
                    $container.css(containerPosition).show();
                }
                if(defaults.effect == 'slide'){
                    $container.css({
                        width: 0,
                        height: 0,
                        opacity: 0});

                    if(defaults.direction == 'right'){

                        $container.show().css({
                            left: megaWidth
                        });
                    } else {

                        $container.show().css({
                            right: megaWidth
                        });
                    }
                    $container.animate({
                            width: width,
                            height: height,                         
                            opacity: 1
                        }, defaults.speed);
                }
            }

            function megaOut(){
                $(this).removeClass('mega-hover');
                var $container = $('.sub-container',this);
                $container.hide();
            }
        });
    };





})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function($){  
// menu slide hoverIntend
$('#rajbrowsecat').hoverIntent({    
     over: startHover,
     out: endHover,
     timeout: 1000
    });

    function startHover(e){   
    $('#rajdropdownmenu').slideDown(200)
 }

 function endHover(){     
     $('#rajdropdownmenu').slideUp(600)
 }
// menu slide hoverIntend


$('#rajmegamenu').dcVerticalMegaMenu({
        rowItems: '5',
        speed: 'fast',
        effect: 'slide',
        direction: 'right',
        menubg: '1',
        menufixwidth: '236',
        menufixheight: '155'
    });


});
```

Comment: So how does it behave now?

Comment: you want some tree like structure

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
  So i managed to do it by diabling all the code (with /*) related to hover effect from the line    "// HoverIntent Configuration" to "// menu slide hoverIntend" and by twicking the css a bit for presentation , seemed to do the trick to always showing submenus but for those who are interested i also found a way by adding to the css the line "height:auto", that also seemed to work fairly nicely.
Anyway thanks guys for yor answers anyway , it's always nice to to know that we have a place you can turn to when we are stuck !